# What is the cmake configuration that will change the project type to .wixproj?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, wix, cmake

I am trying to build a solution for wix project with cmake. But by default it is generating .vcxproj. What is the configuration  in CMakeLists.txt file to change the project type to .wixproj.

Thanks in advance.

The configuration that i am using is:

```
#
### Minimum required version of the cmake
#
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)

#
### Set the Solution name and the language to support by the project
#
PROJECT(Transcend)

#
### Manage CMake Policy settings
#
CMAKE_POLICY(SET CMP0015 NEW)

#
### Additional library directories
#
IF( CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 4 )
LINK_DIRECTORIES(
                              ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/trunk/ext/lib)
ELSE()
LINK_DIRECTORIES(
                              ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/trunk/ext/lib)
ENDIF()


#set(CPACK_WIX_UPGRADE_GUID "8ffd1d72-b7f1-11e2-8ee5-00238bca4991")

INCLUDE(InstallRequiredSystemLibraries)
set(CPACK_GENERATOR WIX)
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "Transcend")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR "CMake.org")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "MyLib - CPack Component Installation Example")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0.0")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "1")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "0")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "0")
SET(CPACK_WIX_INCLUDE "Directory_and_Reference.wxs")
SET(CPACK_WIX_INCLUDE "Feature.wxs")
SET(CPACK_WIX_INCLUDE "Machine__to_Install.wxs")
SET(CPACK_WIX_INCLUDE "Product.wxs")
SET(CPACK_WIX_INCLUDE "Shortcut_menu.wxs")
SET(CPACK_WIX_INCLUDE "User_Interface.wxs")
SET(CPACK_WIX_INCLUDE "UserRegistrationDlg.wxs")

INCLUDE(CPack)
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't. WiX is concerned with packaging, and that's the domain of CPack. As of CMake/CPack version 2.8.11, there is WiX support provided: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#module:CPackWIX. For general instruction on using CPack, refer to http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:Packaging_With_CPack.

Comment: I have some .wxs files to generate .msi installer. I am not understanding what configuration need to write in CMakeLists.txt file to generate installer. What are the commands should i need to use to generate the installer ?

Comment: I added the configuration that i am using but it is not working. What's the mistake in that please tell me.

Comment: Ah, you already *have* an existing WiX project that you want to include in your build? The solution I proposed automatically would generate a WiX project for you (based on a template, which might not always suit your needs...). If you want to just build the existing WiX project, you will want to look into the [`include_external_msproject()`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command:include_external_msproject) command.

Comment: I want to generate the new wix project with available .wxs files.How can i include those .wxs files in CMakeLists.txt . What is the cmake command to generate wixproject and build the wix project.

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to do that. Either let CPack do everything for you, or supply an existing `.wixproj`. You might have more luck asking on the [CMake-users mailing list](http://www.cmake.org/mailman/listinfo/cmake).

Comment: Now I am using include_external_msproject(projectName wixprojectpath) in CMakeLists.txt. Then what is the command that i need to use to build that project.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. Never used WiX and include_external_msproject() myself. I suppose there should be a target now which you can either build manually or depend on.

Comment: @123r789 That brings you back around to my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18398591/2226988) to your first question about WiX. The easiest way is to create a .wixproj. Then you only need to run a command like `msbuild /target:Rebuild /property:Configuration=Release /property:Platform=x86 the.wixproj`.

Comment: I guess you could make that (msbuild command from the above comment) as a custom command so that it would integrate into cmake based projects.